# Discord.js channel isn't defined welcome message

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

Im finding myself stuck with defining the "channel" and i keep getting channel not defind im definetly 
new to JS but i thought i covered defining could someone help me out here ive tried to define it with a var channel = , and a let channel but cant seem to get any to work.

```
    client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
        const guild = member.guild;
        newUsers.set(member.id, member.user);
        if (newUsers.size > 1) {
          const defaultChannel = guild.channels.find(channel => channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"));
          const userlist = newUsers.map(u => u.toString()).join(" ");
          defaultChannel.send("Welcome to the server!\n" + userlist);
          newUsers.clear();
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That repo you are using is not updated. Try with this

```
const defaultChannel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "NAME");
```

Comment: still getting same problem hmm